# I can't get the canvas width in react

Tags: reactjs

```
console.log(canvas);   
console.log(canvas.width);  
console.log(canvas.getAttribute("width"));
```

[image]

In the first line you can see that react is able to get the canvas element from the DOM (via `ref`), but the output from second and third line is wrong! I am unable to get the correct width, which is confusing... what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `getBoundingClientRect()`.
Assuming you gave ref attribute to canvas element as "mycanvas", You can do `this.refs.mycanvas.getBoundingClientRect().width`

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` gives you the native DOM node, then you need to use the regular DOM APIs to access attributes. You can do either `event.target.dataset.tag` or `event.target.getAttribute('data-tag')`; either one works.